# Assign Array type reference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pass-by-reference

In Swift `Array` is struct, so when I assign an array to another array of another `Object`, the value of this array will be copied to another one.
 
 For example:

```
class File {
   var subFile: [File]?
}

let file = File(file:foo)
file.subFile = otherarray
```

How can I assign Array type in reference?
 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code makes no sense(it doesn't compile) so your question is completely unclear. What does "How can I assign Array type in reference?" mean? What _result_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think the @matt comment is valid. Why do you need to copy the reference? Explain more about your issue

Comment: Wrap the array in a class.